# HackerRank "filled orders" problem with Python

Tags: python

Recently *[HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/skills-verification/problem_solving)* launched their own certifications. Among the tests they offer is "Problem Solving". The test contains 2 problems; they give you 90 minutes to solve them. Being inexperienced as I am, I failed, because it took me longer than that.

Specifically, I came up with the solution for the first problem (*filled orders*, see below) in, like 30 minutes, and spent the rest of the time trying to debugg it. The problem with it wasn't that the solution didn't work, but that *it worked on only some of the test cases*.

**Out of 14 testcases the solution worked on 7** (including all the open ones and a bunch of closed ones), and **didn't work on the remaining 7** (all closed). Closed means that the input data is not available, as well as expected output. (Which makes sense, because some of the lists there included 250K+ elements.)

But it drives me crazy; I can't figure out what might be wrong with it. I tried putting print statements all over the place, but the only thing I came to is that *1 too many elements get added to the list* - hence, the last `if` statement (to drop the last added element), but it made no difference whatsoever, so it's probably wrong.

Here's the problem:

> A widget manufacturer is facing unexpectedly high demand for its new product,. They would like to satisfy as many customers as possible. Given a number of widgets available and a list of customer orders, what is the maximum number of orders the manufacturer can fulfill in full?
>
> Function Description
>
> Complete the function filledOrders in the editor below. The function must return a single integer denoting the maximum possible number of fulfilled orders.
>
> filledOrders has the following parameter(s):
>
> order :  an array of integers listing the orders
>
> k : an integer denoting widgets available for shipment
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 ≤ n ≤  2 x 105
>
> 1 ≤  order[i] ≤  109
>
> 1 ≤ k ≤ 109
>
> Sample Input For Custom Testing
>
> 2
>
> 10
>
> 30
>
> 40
>
> Sample Output
>
> 2

And here's my function:

```
def filledOrders(order, k):
    total = k
    fulf = []
    for r in order:
        if r <= total:
            fulf.append(r)
            total -= r
        else:
            break

    if sum(fulf) > k:
        fulf.pop()
        
    return len(fulf)
```

Comment: Offhand would say `filledOrders` will cover more orders if they were sorted in ascending order first (i.e. for `r in sorted(order):`.  Also, why are you appending to array in a loop.  This makes the function O(n^2) which is problematic for larger test cases.  You only need to keep track of the number of orders processed before you exceed k.

Comment: very good point about the sorting; didn't even think of that.

Comment: so... a `while` loop?

Comment: @DenisShvetsov--placed suggested code in answer.

Comment: @DarrylG May I know what is wrong with [this](https://pastebin.com/yDcLqLLg)

Comment: @Pyd -- array `order` needs to be sorted first in ascending order.  For instance, suppose `k  = 6; order = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.  Without sorting your method return 0, when the answer is 3 (i.e. processing orders 1, 2, 3).

Comment: thank you, I did not focus on `maximum possible number of fulfilled orders. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code Revision**

```
def filledOrders(order, k):
  total = 0
  for i, v in enumerate(sorted(order)):
    if total + v <= k:
      total += v       # total stays <= k
    else:
      return i         # provides the count
  else:
    return len(order)  # was able to place all orders

print(filledOrders([3, 2, 1], 3))  # Out: 2
print(filledOrders([3, 2, 1], 1))  # Out: 1
print(filledOrders([3, 2, 1], 10)) # Out: 3
print(filledOrders([3, 2, 1], 0))  # Out: 0
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java Solution

```
int count = 0;
        Collections.sort(order);
        for(int i=0; i<order.size(); i++) {
            if(order.get(i)<=k) {
                count++;
                k = k - order.get(i);
            } 
        }
        return count;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Advanced Javascript solution :**

```
function filledOrders(order, k) {
    // Write your code here
 let count = 0; let total=0;
  const ordersLength = order.length;
  const sortedOrders = order.sort(function(a,b) {
  return (+a) - (+b);
});

  for (let i = 0; i < ordersLength; i++) {
    if (total + sortedOrders[i] <= k) {
        // if all orders able to be filled
      if (total <= k && i === ordersLength - 1) return ordersLength;

      total += sortedOrders[i];
      count++;
    } else {
      return count;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on SO. Consider adding an explanation to help future visitors learn important elements of your solution, so they can apply this info to their own coding issues. Quality answers are upvoted over time, mostly by future visitors gaining insight from your explanations. Welcome, & thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

Python code

```
    def filledOrders(order, k):
      orderfulfilled=0
      for i in range(1,len(order)):
        m=k-order[i]
        if(m>=0):
           orderfulfilled+=1
           k-=order[i]
      return(orderfulfilled)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Javascript solution

    Option1:
    
    function filledOrders(order, k) {
    
        let count=0;
        let arr= [];
        arr = order.sort().filter((item, index) => {
            if (item<=k) {
                k = k - item;
                return item
            }
        })
        return arr.length
    }
    
    Option2:
    
    function filledOrders(order, k) {
        let count=0;
        for(var i=0; i<order.sort().length; i++) {
            if(order[i]<=k) {
                count++;
                k = k - order[i]
            } 
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

C#

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;

class Result
{

    /*
     * Complete the 'filledOrders' function below.
     *
     * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
     * The function accepts following parameters:
     *  1. INTEGER_ARRAY order
     *  2. INTEGER k
     */

    public static int filledOrders(List<int> order, int k)
    {

        if (order.Sum() <= k)
        {
            return order.Count();
        }
        else
        {
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (int element in order)
            {

                if (element <= k)
                {
                    counter++;
                    k = k - element;


                }
            }
            return counter;
        }


    }

}

class Solution
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        

        int orderCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

        List<int> order = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < orderCount; i++)
        {
            int orderItem = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
            order.Add(orderItem);
        }

        int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
        var orderedList = order.OrderBy(a=>a).ToList();
        int result = Result.filledOrders(orderedList, k);

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for giving an answer. Your answer would be more helpful if you explain why the code you posted works- could you perhaps edit your answer to include that?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the better way to approach (to decrease time complexity) is to solve without use of sorting. (Ofcourse, that comes that cost of readability)

Below is a solution without use of sort. (Not sure if I covered all edge cases.)

```
import os, sys

def max_fulfilled_orders(order_arr, k):
    
    # track the max no.of orders in the arr.
    max_num = 0
    # order count, can be fulfilled.
    order_count = 0
    
    # iter over order array
    for i in range(0, len(order_arr)):
        # if remain value < 0 then
        if k - order_arr[i] < 0:
            # add the max no.of orders to total
            k += max_num
            if order_count > 0:
                # decrease order_count
                order_count -= 1
                
        # if the remain value >= 0
        if(k - order_arr[i] >= 0):
            # subtract the current no.of orders from total.
            k -= order_arr[i]
            # increase the order count.
            order_count += 1
            # track the max no.of orders till the point.
            if order_arr[i] > max_num:
                max_num = order_arr[i]

    return order_count


print(max_fulfilled_orders([3, 2, 1], 0))  # Out: 0
print(max_fulfilled_orders([3, 2, 1], 1))  # Out: 1
print(max_fulfilled_orders([3, 1, 1], 2))  # Out: 2
print(max_fulfilled_orders([3, 2, 4], 9)) # Out: 3
print(max_fulfilled_orders([3, 2, 1, 4], 10)) # Out: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In python,

```
def order_fillers(order,k):
    if len(order)==0 or k==0:
        return 0
    order.sort()
    max_orders=0
    for item in order:
        if k<=0:
            return max_orders
        if item<=k:
            max_orders+=1
            k-=item
    return max_orders
```

Answer (score -1):

## JavaScript Solution

```js
function filledOrders(order, k) {
  let total = 0;
  let count = 0;
  const ordersLength = order.length;
  const sortedOrders = order.sort();

  for (let i = 0; i < ordersLength; i++) {
    if (total + sortedOrders[i] <= k) {
        // if all orders able to be filled
      if (total <= k && i === ordersLength - 1) return ordersLength;

      total += sortedOrders[i];
      count++;
    } else {
      return count;
    }
  }
}

// Validation
console.log(filledOrders([3, 2, 1], 3)); //  2
console.log(filledOrders([3, 2, 1], 1)); // 1
console.log(filledOrders([3, 2, 1], 10)); // 3
console.log(filledOrders([3, 2, 1], 0)); // 0
console.log(filledOrders([3, 2, 2], 1)); // 0
```

Comment: This doesn't pass the same 7 test cases that are failing for OP.